# Moving a image on the CSS page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my small Facebook logo icon to the top left of the page though currently it is showing 1/4 way down. please could you look at my CSS code incase i have done something wrong.

CSS;

```
html,body {
background-image:url(../img/background.png);
background-size:cover;
}

 #social  {
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:50px;
height:100px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;

}

#bar {  
margin-top:55px;
min-width:1000px center;
max-width:1920px;
height: 30px;
background: #2E2E2E;
border: 3.2px groove #FFD700;
}
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
#middle
{
height:10000px;
}

#social  {
margin-left:50px;
height:100px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;

}

.facebook {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
}
```

and my HTML is:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="social">
<div class="facebook"></div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for your help

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or Codepen to aid in your question.

Comment: a fiddle helps people who shows interest in giving a suggestion to your question.... jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

you declared `#social` two times

try to set the absolute position with top and left (or resetting them to 0px and doing your margin-stuff)

```
#social  {
    top:       20px;
    left:      50px;
    height:   100px;
    width:    200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:  2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

- You defined `#social` as `position: absolute` and then used a `margin-*` property for the positioning, which shouldn't work because it is taken out of the document flow.
- You have defined CSS for the id `social` twice, in which case the last definition encountered will take precedence

My recommendation would be to use `left` and `top` properties instead of `margin-left` and `margin-top`, and to delete the topmost `#social` style definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
.facebook {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

please use `top`,`left`,`right` and `bottom` which would be appropriate where you are using `positions`.using `margin-left` etc for positioning will not make your code syntactical.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `margin-top:20px;` attribute in your `#social` ID. Is this meant to be there?

**Note:** You have two `#social` IDs declared, please remove one of them so they don't collide with each other.

Try setting

```
.facebook {
    background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png) top left;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-size:32px;
}
```

**Suggestion:** If your background size will always be 32x32, I suggest you use a 32x32 image instead of a 64x64 as the URL suggests.